# Cache options so @Postload annotated method dont get called everytime Hibernate is asked to retrieve object

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, caching, spring-data-jpa

I have a class annotated with JPA `@Entity` annotation, so objects of this class persist in database and are managed using Hibernate ORM. In my class constructor, a connection to a MQTT broker is created, so each object during initialization stablish a TCP connection.

When a object data is fetch from the database, this constructor can not be used by the ORM, as ORM uses default constructor without arguments, so I put the code that stablish the connection in a `@PostLoad` annotated method.

The problem is, everytime the web application page is refreshed the ORM is asked to get the object, and the `@Postload` method is executed so the TCP connection is stablished again... but I want the connection to be stablished only the first time object is fetch from database, and no everytime page is refreshed.

So the solution would be a ORM with in memory object cache. This way the first time object is loaded from database the `@Postload` method is called, but next times ORM is asked to retrieve the object it is retrieved from cache.

I dont know if this is possible with Hibernate, I have been playing with cache options and `@Cacheable` annotation but it seems that `@Postload` method is called everytime I use the `findById` method of Repository class, no matter the cache options I set. So I guess Hibernate cache is caching table rows, no objects in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an entity manager with an extended persistence context which spans multiple transactions, but I have no idea how or if Spring Data supports this. This way, the entity would not be reloaded from the database but be part of this extended persistence context. Note though, that this comes with other issues.

Usually, such expensive operations are simply not done in entities. You could move the logic out of the class, or do some kind of connection pooling/caching to avoid reconnects. I don't know why you need a dedicated connection, but connecting to message brokers is usually done differently. Usually, such connections are pooled by some context object of the library or maybe Spring offers some integration with options for pooling. In Java/Jakarta EE, this is usually done through resource adapters. I bet there is a JMS implementation for MQTT that you could use, probably also with Spring. AFAIK, in Spring Data JPA, you usually fire a domain/application event and react to that somewhere else. In that listener you could publish a message to a topic/queue through JMS or the native MQTT library.

Comment: Well, the connection to the broker is not done by the entities, but the subscription to a topic (that involves a TCP connection) is triggered by the entitie using a MQTT library. Entity is a sensor and measures are published in topics, so I dont want the subscription/unsubscription to be done every time page is refreshed. Now imagine a Printer entity class having a operation like print that involves communication with external device... Maybe Printer class collaborates with other classes to achieve that but at the end print method should be responsible of getting the thing printed shouldn it?

Comment: Sure, but if you care about resources (TCP connections), you will have to pool them somehow. The outside world doesn't need to know about that. I think what you want can be done with Spring Data JPA domain events: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-ddd

Comment: Connections are pooled and managed by a singleton class, but when a sensor object is initialized, a new subscription to a topic is done. I dont want that everytime I get the same object from JPARepository (that involves initialization of new Sensor object), because the page is refreshed, a subscription to topic is done... Why the object is not cached by the ORM?

Comment: The entity is bound to the persistence context. Usually, the persistence context only spans for a transaction, but you can extend it to span as long as you want. This way, the object will stay in that persistence context and subsequent find calls will return that existing object. If you use Java EE, use `@PersistenceContext(EXTENDED)` or create a custom `EntityManager` and keep that instance around as it represents the persistence context.